# How do I start Rails Console from Rakefile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, rails-console, rakefile

I need to be able to start the rails console for my app from a rake take, but I am having some trouble. I added the following task to my Rakefile:

```
task :console do
  sh 'cd rails-root && rails console'
end
```

When I run rake console, I get output as if I had typed "rails new" instead of "rails console". I've also tried several different variants of this command, including

```
exec 'cd rails-root && rails console'
sh 'which rails && cd rails-root && bash -l' # and then typing path/to/rails c
load Gem.bin_path('railties', 'rails', '4.2.7.1')
Rails::Command.invoke 'console' # throws an error: uninitialized constant Rails
```

Each of which gives the following output:

```
rails console
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                         # Default: /usr/bin/ruby
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                              # Path to some application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)

... truncating some output ...
Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]                    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend], [--no-pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet], [--no-quiet]      # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip], [--no-skip]        # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help], [--no-help]        # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version], [--no-version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.
```

Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: Are you running this task from a directory inside the rails application hierarchy?

Comment: yes, I can clarify that